# Read the text file from separate folder in java

Tags: java, file, path

I have the following path in my project, i am writing the test for Someclass.java which is named as SomeClassTest.java, In the test i need to read 'sample.txt', but i could not able to read that text file.
The following is my project structure.

```
   src/
      java/
         SomeClass.java

   test/
      java/
         SomeClassTest.java
      resources/
         sample.txt
```

I tried with the following code to read the file.

```
File file = new File("/resources/sample.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
```

the above code is giving fileNotFoundException. May i know what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please see edited post, the test folder is not in src, project folder is having parallel folders 'src' and 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `new File("src/test/resources/sample.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Since `resources` is a package, you can use [`getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to access your file:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/sample.txt");
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
}
```

This function open an `InputStream` on a file located inside your class hierarchy.

If you are executing your code from a static context, you have to use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...)` instead of calling `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use like that.

```
File file = new File("/resources/sample.txt");
```

Because if you start with slash means it will check in root directory.

So You will use `new File("src/test/resources/sample.txt");` like that.

or move the resources directory from src to same level src 
then you can use `new File("resources/sample.txt");` like that.